# Access VBA: Closing form causes duplicate entry in table

Tags: ms-access, vba

Let me explain what I have set up to easily describe my issue. I created a child form based on a table, which for illustration looks like this sample:

[image]

Each `Text Box` is bounded, i.e. its `Control Source` points to the appropriate field name from the table.

There is a save `Command Button` at the bottom where I have added some vba code to insert the 4 field values into the table.

Once the save button is clicked I do the following to insert into the table, and  close the form:

```
db.Execute "INSERT INTO testTable (Number, Name, OtherNumber, OtherName) " _
        & "VALUES (" & Me.Number & ", '" & Me.Name _ 
        & Me.OtherNumber & "', '" & Me.OtherName & "')"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmTest", acSaveNo
```

The problem is that once the form is closed, it creates a duplicate entry in the table.

Due to my unfamiliarity with vba programming at the moment, I know that it has to do with the bounded textboxes to the table because if I remove the `Control Source` fields from the textboxes, leaving it blank, and manually fetch the values in the textboxes instead, i.e. `Me.textBox_OtherNumber`, then insert those values into the table when the save button is clicked, I don't get a duplicate entry in the table when the form is closed.

**However**, I would prefer the textboxes be bounded to the table because this makes it easier to open the form up in either `acFormAdd` mode where the field values are empty and waiting to be added as a **new** record, or the form is opened up in `acFormEdit` mode where the field values is already populated with the values from the selected row in the table using a `WHERE` criteria clause parameter in the `DoCmd.OpenForm`.

For example, I have a parent form that contains a `Command Button` and `subform`. The subform's `Source Object` is linked to a `Datasheet` whose `Record Source` is linked to the same table as the child form.

In the field `OtherNumber` of the `Datasheet`, I created a `hyperlink` and programmed its `On Click` command to be like so:

```
Dim uniqID As Integer
Dim criteria As String

uniqID = Me.ID
criteria = "ID = " & uniqID 

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmTest", acNormal, , criteria, acFormEdit
```

When a particular `hyperlink` of a specific row is clicked, the fields  in `frmTest` is populated with the data based on the `criteria`, which will be used to **update** the current record.

However, if the `Command Button` is clicked in the parent form, I do the following:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmTest", acNormal, , , acFormAdd
```

The form is opened but the field values are blank, indicating a new record is about to be added based on the field values.

To me, this feels like it is much easier than not having the textboxes in `frmTest` bounded to anything, and if it is not bounded, I would have to figure out a way to reference the field values in the `Datasheet` and pass to the child form `frmTest`.

Do you see my dilemma? What's the best way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you're doing some pretty weird stuff. What's the code behind that save button? Is it an insert statement? Because if you're working with a bound form, any data operations should be done through the forms recordset

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many, many ways to solve this problem:

Using a bound form, on your save button, just omit the line to save the record (since Access automatically saves it):

```
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo
```

Or, if you don't trust Access to save it:

```
Me.Recordset.Update
'Or: DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
'Or: If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo
```

Note that `acSaveNo` refers to not saving any changes to the *design* of the form, and is not related to saving records in any way.

If you want to set values on an unbound form from another form:

```
If Not Application.SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, acForm, "frmTest") Then 
    'You probably don't want to run this if the form is already opened
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmTest"
    frmTest!ID.Value = uniqID
End If
```

(of course, there are many alternatives to this as well. The most relevant one is you can pass arguments between forms using the `OpenArgs` parameter of `DoCmd.OpenForm`, and you can handle those on form load).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, in regards to the first suggestion, omitting `DoCmd.Close` will obviously solve the issue, but how would I go about closing the form automatically once the save button is clicked?...which is what I prefer

Comment: apologize...I read too quickly.....that works as you mentioned, but how would I prevent Access from auto saving if the Close (X) button was clicked instead of the save button?

Comment: Access auto-saves at a lot of events. I could show you how to suppress all saving, but if you only suppress it on close, it would likely already be autosaved before